# Jquery mobile - Select Menu doesn't refresh the display value

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use a pick list in my mobile App using Select Menu. I have picked up below example from jquerymobile website. It creates the popup list and shows the default first value (i.e. Standard: 7 day). However if I use the popup to select a different value, say "Rush: 3 days", it doesn't update the display value. If I open it again I can see "Rush: 3 days" selected in the popup but the display value remains unchanged.

```
<label for="select-choice-min" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
<select name="select-choice-min" id="select-choice-min" data-mini="true" onchange="ChangeValue(this.value);">
   <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
   <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
   <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
   <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
```

I even tried to manually Refresh using onchange() which didn't work:

```
function ChangeValue (z) {

    $('#select-choice-min').selectmenu('refresh');

}
```

Here are a few screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

JQuery: jquery-2.1.4.min.js
JQM:  jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

Comment: try this : `$("#select-choice-min").html(optionList).selectmenu('refresh', true);`.https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-add-items-and-refresh-the-select-menu-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: What should the "optionList" contain?

Comment: [See the fiddle its working](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pwmr1dae/). i was change the library version

Comment: On fiddle its working even without the refresh method. See this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/pwmr1dae/1/ But its not working on chrome or my mobile.

Comment: In fact any of the above two refresh methods breaks the code. If I apply an alert after that it never reaches that. But any alert before that does work and display the correct z value

Comment: have you tried this version of refresh:? $("#select-choice-min").selectmenu("refresh", true);

Comment: Yes, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 does not work completely fine with jQuery **2**.X.X. If it is possible try using jQuery **1**.X.X, should work.